# UIStoryboard Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I don't know what's happen but the following method give the following error:

> Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle
>   /var/mobile/Applications/D5A43DEA-5070-4167-A375-C22E2C1F22DF/prova.app

I have created a new project and I edit the  ViewController's method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Do you actually have a file called MainStoryboard.storyboard in your project and copied to your bundle?

Comment: Or `MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard` or `MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard` if your project is a universal app?